# Net Core Dynamic Model Binding

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization

I'm trying to build an authorization system not only based in user -> permissions -> roles -> groups but also in entities -> properties.

So i want to limit the model binding in post and put requests so I can verify which properties the user has permission to update or create, and then let him/her update or create the entity ... else reject the request.

Maybe its a idea too complex but I wanted to have the same functionality as some CMS online.

I was reading and maybe this can be solved with a Custom Model Binder, I'm learning a lot about it but, I wanna know if this is "the right path" or maybe there is a faster or better way to do it

Thank you so much, I'll keep updating my question with code so, maybe can help someone in future with the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on exactly the same thing, and I do believe it's entirely possible to do this with custom `[Attributes]`. Here's a small implementation of how I've done it in dynamic select-statements:

Firstly, I have a custom attribute that takes an enum UserRoles as input:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class RestrictUserRoles : Attribute
{
    public RestrictUserRoles(UserRoles roles)
    {
        Roles = roles;
    }

    public UserRoles Roles { get; }
}
```

The UserRoles-enum can be implemented as such:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserRoles
{
    [Description("Administrator")]
    Admin = 1,
    [Description("Employee")]
    Employee = 2,
    [Description("Head of a division")]
    DivisionHead = 4,
    [Description("Fired")]
    Fired = 8
}
```

I use an enum because some employees can be admin, divisionheads (and even fired).

I then have an IQueryable extension where it gets all the properties that a user is authorized to see and intersects those properties with those selected. To do this I use dynamic Linq and reflection.

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable SelectProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, UserRoles roles, string criteria)
    {
        // get all the properties that a user is authorized to see
        var authenticatedProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(prop => prop.CustomAttributes.Any(attr =>
                attr.AttributeType == typeof(RestrictUserRoles) &&
                (((RestrictUserRoles) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(RestrictUserRoles))).Roles & roles) !=
                0))
            .Select(prop => prop.Name)
            .ToList();

        // if there aren't any, then the user is not
        // authorized to view any properties
        // DISCLAIMER: or someone has forgotten to mark any properties
        // with the RestrictUserRoles-attribute
        if (!authenticatedProperties.Any()) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

        // we get all the properties that the user wants to 
        // select from the string that was passed to the function in 
        // the form Prop1, Prop2, Prop3
        var selectProperties = criteria
            .Split(',')
            .Select(property => property.Trim());

        // Get the intersection between these properties, IE we
        // select only those properties that the user has selected
        // AND is authorized to view
        var properties = authenticatedProperties
            .Intersect(selectProperties)
            .ToList();

        // if there are none that intersect, return all those
        // properties that a user is authorized to view
        if (!properties.Any()) properties = authenticatedProperties;

        // run the query using dynamic linq
        return source.Select("new(" + properties.JoinToString(",") + ")");
    }
}
```

This isn't field-tested, but it should do the trick and is easily extendable to mutations.

EDIT: forgot that I use an extension-function to join all properties that I define below:

```
public static string JoinToString(this IEnumerable<string> list, string delimiter = "")
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, list);
}
```

Comment: What if we create a github repo and share our approaches, mine its more easy using https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/